# ASP.NET Core External Login Facebook Issue

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core

I have an issue in ASP.NET Core with Facebook external login, it's working fine locally in the localhost but returns the below error when redirect to /signin-facebook?code=xxxxxxx in the production environment.

**Error Message:** An error was encountered while handling the remote login

**Source:** Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication

**Error Stack Trace:** at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)Error Stack Trace String

Startup.cs

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TakolA.ContentResources;
using TakolA.Models;
using TakolA.UnitOfWork;
using TakolA.UnitOfWork.Data;
using TakolA.UnitOfWork.Helpers;
using TakolA.ViewModels;
using TakolA.Web.Filters;
using TakolA.Web.Helpers;
using TakolA.Web.Middlewares;
using TakolA.Web.Services;

namespace TakolA.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public string MyAllowSpecificOrigins { get; } = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(Options =>
            {
                Options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider = "Email";
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie((options) =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = CookiesKeys.AuthenticationCookieName;
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error/AccessDenied");
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            });

            services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/AccessDenied";
            });

            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = CookiesKeys.AntiforgeryCookieName;
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://takol-eh.com/").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost/").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost/").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44378/").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:50419/").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            //Add Hangfire services
            services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new()
                {
                    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                    DisableGlobalLocks = true,
                    PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true
                })
                .UseSerializerSettings(new()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                }));

            // Add the processing server as IHostedService
            services.AddHangfireServer(options =>
            {
                options.Queues = HangfireHelper.GetQueues();
            });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = CookiesKeys.SessionCookieName;
            });

            services.AddLocalization(o => { o.ResourcesPath = ""; });

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; })
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => { options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(Resources)); })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Latest);

            services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddScoped<IHtmlTemplateHelper, HtmlTemplateHelper>();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork>();
            services.DatabaseMigration();
            services.AddAuthorizationPolicies();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IUnitOfWork uow, IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
                
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("ar-EG") };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            {
                RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider> {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider { QueryStringKey = "culture" },
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider { CookieName = CookiesKeys.CultureCookieName }
                },
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            BackgroundJobsHelper backgroundJobsHelper = new (uow);
            recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("HourlyTask_DailyRecommendation", () => backgroundJobsHelper.HourlyTask_DailyRecommendation(), "0 * * * *");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.RefreshSignIn();

            app.Localization();

            //app.CookiesHandler();

            app.CacheHandler(uow);

            app.RequestLog(uow);

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/BackgroundProcesses", new DashboardOptions
            {
                DashboardTitle = "Background Processes",
                AppPath = "#",
                IsReadOnlyFunc = (DashboardContext context) => HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter.IsReadOnly(context),
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter() }
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

External Login Actions

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction("SuccessLoginRedirect");
            return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string returnUrl, string provider)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction("SuccessLoginRedirect");
            var redirectUrl = $"/Account/ExternalLoginCallBack?returnUrl={returnUrl}";
            var properties = uow.SignInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallBack(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return RedirectToAction("SuccessLoginRedirect");
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                TempData["Error"] = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl });
            }

            ExternalLoginInfo info = await uow.SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Error loading external login information.";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl });
            }

            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await uow.SignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) || returnUrl == "/") return RedirectToAction("SuccessLoginRedirect");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
                if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email))
                {
                    RegistrationViewModel model = new()
                    {
                        IsExternalRegistraiotn = true,
                        ExternalRegistraiotnProviderDisplayName = info.ProviderDisplayName,
                        Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                        FirstName = info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName) ? info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName) : null,
                        LastName = info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname) ? info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname) : null,
                        PhoneNumber = info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.MobilePhone) ? info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone) : null,
                    };

                    model.UserName = ($"{model.FirstName}{model.LastName}").Replace(" ", "");

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PhoneNumber) && info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.HomePhone))
                    {
                        model.PhoneNumber = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.HomePhone);
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PhoneNumber) && info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.OtherPhone))
                    {
                        model.PhoneNumber = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.OtherPhone);
                    }

                    if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Gender))
                    {
                        string gender = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Gender);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender) && gender.ToLower() == "male") model.Gender = Gender.Male;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender) && gender.ToLower() == "female") model.Gender = Gender.Female;
                    }

                    return View("Register", model);
                }

                TempData["Error"] = $"Your {info.ProviderDisplayName} account has not email address.";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your Startup.cs and the action which contains redirect?

Comment: @YiyiYou Thanks for your response, I have updated the question by add the Startup.cs and external login actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I took two steps. First, I purchased an SSL certificate. Second, I disabled the free CloudFlare SSL certificate. After taking these steps, the issue was resolved and the Facebook external login feature is now working properly.